# Why Do Harmonic Components Define Wavelength in Diffraction and Interference Phenomena?

Tags: optics, waves, harmonic-oscillator, diffraction, wavelength

I'm exploring the physical principles underlying diffraction and interference, specifically how these phenomena depend on the wavelength of harmonic (sinusoidal) components of a wave. My question centers on understanding why the wavelength of these harmonic components is crucial in determining the behavior of waves in diffraction and interference, as opposed to the wavelengths of components from other periodic waveforms like square or triangular waves.

1. What is the physical reason behind the dependency of diffraction and interference patterns on the wavelengths of the sinusoidal components of a wave?
2. In the case of a complex non periodic wave, why don't the wavelengths of the decomposition of the original wave in a basis composed of triangular or square waves play a dominant role in determining the diffraction and interference patterns? And instead the wavelength that caracterizes the diffraction is the one of the sinusoidal wave decomposition?
3. Is there a fundamental physical principle or property of harmonic waves that makes their wavelengths particularly significant in these phenomena, compared to other periodic waveforms?

I'm looking to deepen my understanding of the physical principles at play and would greatly appreciate any insights or explanations you can provide on why harmonic wavelengths are so pivotal in diffraction and interference.

Comment: The physical principle that matters here is that waves are free of self-interaction. Did you study the solution theory of linear partial differential equations?

Comment: The analysis is relatively straightforward when considering sinusoidal frequency components as the basis and then used the results to find the effect on other wave-forms by addition.

Comment: Scattering/diffraction off a metal object in a homogeneous medium is essentially a linear time invariant process, hence linear time independent operator techniques are applicable whose eigenfunctions are complex sinusoids; Fourier transform is the easiest and most appropriate technique. There have been attempts to use the Walsh-Hadamard functions besides in spread spectrum communications applications but not very successfully, see, https://doi.org/10.1016/S0065-2539(08)61120-8

Comment: EM diffraction through an opening in a screen is mostly an *edge* effect combined interfering with the Huygens wavelets. If the edges are far away relative to the wavelength then most of the incident wave goes through unaffected. Contrariwise, if the edges are close then the diffracted wave is almost as much as the one between the edges and there is a strong effect.

Comment: Sinusoidals are the solutions to wave equations. A perfect triangular wave is composed of an infinite amount of harmonics of the fundamental frequency of that wave, ie, it's composed of an infinite amount of sinusoidal waves. The reason why is because the tip of a triangle wave becomes non-differentiable, or in a not completely accurate analogy, you need an infinite "resolution" to resolve the tip of a triangle wave - hence the need for an infinite number of (sinusoidal) harmonics. Sinusoidals naturally arise, and they can describe all other waves.

Comment: @JoseAndrade the lack of smoothness is not necessarily a problem, one can imagine a resonant structure whose eigenfunctions are very nearly the Walsh functions, or triangular functions, etc., but still applying them would be awkward, as an example see https://patents.google.com/patent/US4506267A/en

Comment: @José Andrade any function of the form F(x+vt)+G(x-vt) is a solution to the wave equation, not only sines and cosines. The same way you talk about decomposing a triangle wave with sinusoids, you could talk about decomposing sinusoids or any other wave as a sum of triangular waves of different frequencies. why don't do that?

Comment: Thanks @hyportnex but how do we know that scattering/diffraction off a metal object in a homogeneous medium is essentially a linear time invariant process. How is it proved?
So we decompose in sinusoids because trough LTIs systems, they come out with the same wave shape, only changing on amplitude or frequency?
There is no other wave that could be eigenfunction apart from sine? Is there a proof?

Comment: EM propagation in a homogeneous medium is governed by the Helmholtz equation, interaction with "metallic" obstacles are given by linear boundary conditions, both are from the Maxwell's equations, and taken together they form a *linear time invariant* system mathematically.

Comment: Thank you @hyportnex , but linearity in physics isn't an idealization? For example, non linear optics, is nearer to the real thing than linear optics right?

Comment: And @hyportnex, you say "Scattering/diffraction off a metal object in a homogeneous medium is essentially a linear time invariant process, hence linear time independent operator techniques are applicable whose eigenfunctions are complex sinusoids"
But aren't there more eigenfunctions apart from complex sinusoids? Is it the only one?  Is there a proof?

Comment: see section exponentials and eigen functions in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_time-invariant_system

Comment: @hyportnex thanks but there it isn't specified if the complex exponential is the only eigenfunction possible or if there are more

Comment: that is true but the complex exponentials do form a complete system of eigenfunctions, that is all square integrable functions can be represented  as the the linear sum of of complex exponentials, a Fourier transform and that is enough.

Comment: @hyportnex does that mean that all functions are eigenfunctions of LTIs then?

Comment: not at all, if $A[x_1]=a_1x_1$ and $A[x_2]=a_2x_2$ with $a_1\ne a_2$  then $y=c_1x_1+c_2x_2$ is not an eigenfunction of $A$: $A[y]=c_1a_1x_1+c_2a_2x_2 \ne b(c_1x_1+c_2x_2)=by$

Comment: @hyportnex Then what is the set of all eigenfunctions of an LTI?

Comment: sorry, i do not know, maybe you should ask it here https://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I did https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4848806/is-the-complex-exponential-the-only-eigenfunction-of-lti-systems